# NVMe Drive not Detected on Linux

Tags: linux, ssd, raid, kali-linux, intel-rst

I am running Kali Linux and it won't see my NVMe m2 drive

If I turn off Intel rapid storage technology in the bios then it will work but i will no be able to use windows anymore. Any way to fix this?

I looked around online and couldn't find another solution? I can't set SATA to AHCI without losing my raid array.

Comment: M.2 and SATA configurations are known to have issues in several platforms, it's seems Intel RST conflicts with devices plugged to PCIe M.2 connector, see here: [https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490H3TSAU/rapid-storage-technology-and-ssd-m2-pcie?language=en_US]. What about an USB 3.0 install for Kali?

Comment: i ended up installing Kali into an usb 3.1 enclosure with an EVO 860 pro ssd with UASP support. Am i getting the same speed as if i installed it unto the Nvme?

Comment: nope, but it shouldn't be perceptible unless there's a huge amount of storage IO operations happening concurrently.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the SSD back to AHCI. There's no benefit I'm aware of using RST on a single disk anyway. It just adds a layer of complication that's not needed in a single disk environment. They probably enable it on purpose to prevent you from installing Linux.

You can either re-install Windows or search the web. There are many write-ups on how to install the AHCI drivers into Windows, then get it to boot without RST enabled. THe basic steps are:

1. Run MSCONFIG
2. Enable Safe Boot (minimal)
3. Reboot into UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI
4. Boot up into safe mode
5. Run MSCONFIG and disable Safe Boot.
6. Reboot

Obviously, have a backup and pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: The OP has mentioned that he can't convert to AHCI without corrupting his RAID.